# md5 file not generated in Android

Tags: android

I have removed `filename.md5` from my project which is voice recognition with pocket sphinx. But when we save the java file it does not create a `.md5` file.
Generally a `.md5` file is generated when we save the `.java` class.

How can `filename.md5` be generated?

> D/dalvikvm(27742): Trying to load lib/data/data/com.mobiloitte.pocketsphinxapp/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x41556730
>
> D/dalvikvm(27742): Added shared lib /data/data/com.mobiloitte.pocketsphinxapp/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x41556730
>
> D/dalvikvm(27742): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.mobiloitte.pocketsphinxapp/lib/libpocketsphinx_jni.so 0x41556730, skipping init
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: sync/models/lm/cmu07a.dic.md5

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the MD5 hash manually (with an [online tool](http://onlinemd5.com/) for instance), create a your_file.md5 and paste the generated hash in it.

If it still doesn't work, try adding a line with your_file in assets/sync/assets.lst

Answer (score 0):

Copy `assets.xml,build.xml,custom_rule.xml,lint.xml` from the pocketsphinx demo app
and paste it inside your project directory and also copy and the `assets/models/assets.lst` file from the demo app and paste it inside your `assets/models dir`

Goto Project's Properties -> Builders and click New->Ant Builder and 
Under the Buildfile click browse Workspace and select your assets.xml file

Clean and Build

Answer (score 0):

MD5 files are generated by a script in Android Studio. If you are running it in eclipse you can first run it in Android studio and then copy the MD5 files and the entries in the assets list.  I could not find the xml files needed to add the builders from Android Studio but this solution worked for me.